# how to delete required string from csv file

Tags: c#, arrays, search, filestream

hi all try to realize deleting line in some csv file;
example of file:

```
24 august 2013 г.,,14:00,00:00,;
24 august 2013 г.,,14:00,00:00,;
24 august 2013 г.,2342,14:00,00:00,23424;
24 august 2013 г.,2342,14:00,19:00,23424;

criteria - 24 august 2013 г.,2342
```

result must be like

```
 24 august 2013 г.,,14:00,00:00,;
 24 august 2013 г.,,14:00,00:00,;
```

my idea
open file -

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
```

get all data in to array

```
        string lines = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string []result = lines.Split(';');
```

than get criteria for deleting data (some string)

```
        string criteria = dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString()+','
            +eventNameDeleteTextBox.Text.ToString();
sr.Close();
```

search it in array,

```
             int startStr = lines.IndexOf(criteria);//find start position
        int length = lines.IndexOf(';',startStr)-startStr;//find end position
```

delete 
       string dataRemoved = lines.Substring(startStr,length);
            viewTextBox.Text = dataRemoved;

and write in file updated data

```
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs1);

        sw.WriteLine(dataRemoved);
        sw.Close();
```

but it's work not correctly - it;s copy string that must be deleted to the start of the file and remove all ; symbols, where im wrong?

Comment: Wourldn't a `var all=lines.Replace(",2342,",",,").Replace(",23424;",",;");` achieve the same? You can write back the string `all` to the file...

Comment: but if i will need to delete all event from 24 august? idea - user choose date of event and it;s name and then delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, If your file is small then below solution shouldn't be a problem.

```
string rawdata = @"24 august 2013 г.,,14:00,00:00,;
24 august 2013 г.,,14:00,00:00,;
24 august 2013 г.,2342,14:00,00:00,23424;
24 august 2013 г.,2342,14:00,19:00,23424;";//consider this is raw file

string[] lines = rawdata.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (!line.Contains("24 august 2013 г.,2342"))
    {
        result.Add(line);
    }
}
```

now your expected result will be in `result` List. You can create a new file with result List.

If this is not answering your question give more info. I'll try to give better solution.

Comment: try it, but in strange reason i get the same result like before - but think it must be without lines that putted in `Contains`

Comment: in strange reason all data added to the new `List`, and `Contains` not help to not add it. I use somethink like `dateTimePicker.Text.ToString()` , and also try to use `"criteria"` in `Contains` part - result - the same....