# How to delete entry from file

Tags: c#, string, list, csv, filestream

try to delete some entry from csv file, if i know only part of string
code

```
 //open File
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);            
 //divide file entry for separate lines
        string []line = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 // find required entry and create new List without it
        List<string> finalData = new List<string>();
        foreach (var l in line)
        {
            if (!line.Contains((dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString().Trim() + ','+ eventNameDeleteTextBox.Text.ToString().Trim()+',')))
                finalData.Add(l);
        }
  // convert to array
        string toCsvoutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, finalData.ToArray());
      //  viewTextBox1.Text=toCsvoutput; 

        //updateFile
        sr.Close();
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs1);
        sw.WriteLine(toCsvoutput);
        sw.Close();
```

As result - nothing heppend, where i'm wrong?

Comment: Is seems you mischaracterized my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18422577/2530848). In my answer `line` is the iterator variable.  `string[] ` is named `lines` which gives proper meaning too.

Comment: yes i describe what i have thanks to your answer, because i cant't describe all code in comments - better vision in new question, sorry if i offend you, but realy your help was VERY helpfull  - i'm just try to learn it - and need a lot of help

Comment: Nope. Never mind. I thought I completely answered your question. No problem start using `Identifiers(variable names)` as I pointed above. That is the best practice which avoids unnecessary confusion like this.:) happy to help

Comment: many thanks to you help - i very appresiate it. Also found, that for correct storing data using my code i also must to trunc file from all data before writing. Use for it `//trunc all data in file
            FileStream tranc = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Truncate);
            tranc.Close();` if not do this - as result get not proprer valuest stored in file

Comment: Yes exactly. I forget to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace line with l:

```
  if (!l.Contains((dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString().Trim() + ','+ 
    eventNameDeleteTextBox.Text.ToString().Trim()+',')))
     finalData.Add(l);
```

Comment: @Kirill - no, just `l.Contains` instead of `line.Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up a lot:

```
string skipText = (dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString().Trim() + ','+
      eventNameDeleteTextBox.Text.ToString().Trim()+',')

var linesIn = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath);
var linesOut = linesIn.Where(line => ! line.Contains(skipText));
linesOut = linesOut.ToList();  // make sure the file is closed again
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath, linesOut);
```

Comment: I know you just repeat the style of the question, and this is possibly off-topic, but when you concat one character, like the comma, to a string, is their any advantage or disadvantage of using a `char` literal instead of a `string` literal? So writing `str1 + ',' + str2` instead of `str1 + "," + str2`.

Comment: Not much difference, I think a string (`","`) might be slightly more efficient but not noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

the condition in the `foreach` statement probably always pass. you should use debug to check the condition itself, make sure it's what you though.

also, you should do

```
string condition = dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString().Trim() + ','+ eventNameDeleteTextBox.Text.ToString().Trim()+',';
```

outside the `foreach` statement, so you won't waste time for nothing.

Comment: yes it always pass - this is a problem, i'll try to put it away

Comment: try - the same - it allways give me a pass? why it;s happend?

Comment: @Kirill when you pass with the debug on the condition, what is the string in "condition", is it in the file you are reading?

Comment: now it's ok - problem was next - i mix variables use line instead of l - like @RezaArab and @ Henk Holterman sad

Comment: @Kirill then accept he's answer, but you should still use the string condition